# Is there a way to mix the Importance weighted VAE with the Beta-VAE?

Tags: variational-autoencoder, importance-sampling, evidence-lower-bound

Is there a way to mix the Importance weighted VAE with the Beta-VAE?

It seems that we cannot separate out the KL-term from the IWAE-ELBO, hence we cannot multiply it with Beta. On the other hand, it would be great to use the Beta-regularisation also in IWAE.

I have tried to search for some papers or implementations for this approach but I have found nothing.